# What's the diference between Task.WhenAll() and foreach(var task in tasks)

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

After a few hours of struggle I found a bug in my app. I considered the 2 functions below to have identical behavior, but it turned out they don't.

Can anyone tell me what's really going on under the hood, and why they behave in a different way?

```
public async Task MyFunction1(IEnumerable<Task> tasks){
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    Console.WriteLine("all done"); // happens AFTER all tasks are finished
}

public async Task MyFunction2(IEnumerable<Task> tasks){
    foreach(var task in tasks){
        await task;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("all done"); // happens BEFORE all tasks are finished
}
```

Comment: "happens BEFORE all tasks are finished" look very strange - can you have  [MCVE] that show this case? I see no reasons why `foreach` would behave the way you described as you `await`-ing all tasks (probably less optimal than `WhenAll` but still all).

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Where's the `return`?

Comment: The general difference between `WhenAll` and manually awaiting them all one-by-one in a loop is that the latter will constantly switch back and forth to the asynchronous method, requiring lots of context switching, while the former awaits them all internally without that overhead.

Comment: @miparnisari The code does compile.  There's no need for a `return`.

Comment: @Servy Ah, my C# skills are getting rusty then haha

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it on simple examples. It was a bit of complicated code (a fake event bus used in integration tests of a quite a big system)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They'll function identically *if all tasks complete successfully*.

If you use `WhenAll` and any items fail, it still won't be completed until all of the items are finished, and it'll represent an `AggregatException` that wraps *all* errors from *all* tasks.

If you `await` each one then it'll complete as soon as it hits *any* item that fails, and it'll represent an exception for that *one* error, not any others.

---

The two also differ in that `WhenAll` will materialize the entire `IEnumerable` right at the start, before adding any continuations to other items.  If the `IEnumerable` represents a collection of already existing and started tasks, then this isn't relevant, but if the act of iterating the enumerable creates and/or starts tasks, then materializing the sequence at the start would run them all in parallel, and awaiting each before fetching the next task would execute them sequentially.  Below is a `IEnumerable` you could pass in that would behave as I've described here:

```
public static IEnumerable<Task> TaskGeneratorSequence()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        yield return Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Provided that no exceptions were thrown, what could have caused the situation I described?

Comment: @gisek Cancellation, or an input sequence that creates the task as it is iterated.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the most important functional difference is that `Task.WhenAll` can introduce concurrency when your tasks perform truly asynchronous operations, for example, IO. This may or may not be what you want depending on your situation.

For example, if your tasks are querying the database using the same EF DbContext, the next query would fire as soon as the first one is "in flight" which causes EF to blow up as it doesn't support multiple simultaneous queries using the same context.

That's because you're not awaiting each asynchronous operation individually. You're awaiting a task that represents the completion of all of those asynchronous operations. They can also be completed in any order.

However when you await each one individually in a `foreach`, you only fire the next task when the current one completes, preventing concurrency and ensuring serial execution.

A simple example demonstrating this behavior:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var tasks = new []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.Select(i => OperationAsync(i));

    foreach(var t in tasks)
    {
        await t;
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

static Random _rand = new Random();
public async Task OperationAsync(int number)
{
    // simulate an asynchronous operation
    // taking anywhere between 100 to 3000 milliseconds
    await Task.Delay(_rand.Next(100, 3000));
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

You'll see that no matter how long `OperationAsync` takes, with foreach you always get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 printed. But with `Task.WhenAll` they are executed concurrently and printed in their completion order.