# c# - async/await out of expected order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to get my head around a result of an example I have coded. Here it is:

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var counter1 = new Counter("counter1",string.Empty);
            var counter2 = new Counter("counter2","         ");
            var counter3 = new Counter("counter3","                     ");            

            await Task.WhenAll(counter1.Count(), counter2.Count(), 
counter3.Count());         
        }
    }

public class Counter
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _prefix;

        public Counter(string name, string prefix)
        {
            _name = name;
            _prefix = prefix;
        }

        public async Task Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"{_prefix}{_name}: {i}");
                if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($" is divisible by 2. Yielding");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I would expect the counters to produce an output in which they switch after 2 lines. Instead, starting from counter2, when it counted to 5 it's like it is yielding on its own. What I get is the following:

```
counter1: 0
counter1: 1
counter1: 2 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 0
         counter2: 1
         counter2: 2 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 0
                     counter3: 1
                     counter3: 2 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 3
counter1: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 3
         counter2: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 5
counter1: 6 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 5
                     counter3: 3
counter1: 7
counter1: 8 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 6 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 7
         counter2: 8 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 5
                     counter3: 6 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 7
                     counter3: 8 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 9
                     counter3: 9
                     counter3: 10 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 10 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 9
         counter2: 10 is divisible by 2. Yielding
```

Why is the order not maintained?

Edit1:

I have added the threadId. It seems like the threads are constantly being switched. Why is that? My platform is .NET Core console app on Windows.

```
counter1: 0. ThreadId: 1
counter1: 1. ThreadId: 1
counter1: 2. ThreadId: 1 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 0. ThreadId: 1
         counter2: 1. ThreadId: 1
         counter2: 2. ThreadId: 1 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 0. ThreadId: 1
                     counter3: 1. ThreadId: 1
                     counter3: 2. ThreadId: 1 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 3. ThreadId: 3
counter1: 4. ThreadId: 3 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 3. ThreadId: 4
                     counter3: 4. ThreadId: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 5. ThreadId: 4
                     counter3: 6. ThreadId: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 5. ThreadId: 3
counter1: 6. ThreadId: 3 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 7. ThreadId: 4
                     counter3: 8. ThreadId: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
                     counter3: 9. ThreadId: 4
                     counter3: 10. ThreadId: 4 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 7. ThreadId: 3
counter1: 8. ThreadId: 3 is divisible by 2. Yielding
counter1: 9. ThreadId: 3
counter1: 10. ThreadId: 3 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 3. ThreadId: 5
         counter2: 4. ThreadId: 5 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 5. ThreadId: 5
         counter2: 6. ThreadId: 5 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 7. ThreadId: 5
         counter2: 8. ThreadId: 5 is divisible by 2. Yielding
         counter2: 9. ThreadId: 5
         counter2: 10. ThreadId: 5 is divisible by 2. Yielding
```

Comment: Please add `Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString())` to your loop and post the results. Also, please tag a platform/application type, e.g. .NET Core vs. Framework and WinForms vs. ASP.NET, etc. as these are all slightly different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the diference between Task.WhenAll() and foreach(var task in tasks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092763/whats-the-diference-between-task-whenall-and-foreachvar-task-in-tasks)

Comment: `I would expect Task.WhenAll to: 1. Take one of the methods and execute it` That's not how it works. The method starts executing when you call `.Count()`. `Task.WhenAll` just waits

Comment: But i do call .Count() in this line:

await Task.WhenAll(counter1.Count(), counter2.Count(), 
counter3.Count());

Comment: And? This is strictly equivalent to `var task1 = counter1.Count(); var task2 = counter2.Count(); var task3 = counter3.Count(); await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);` Maybe it's easier to understand that way

Comment: I get it that it starts executing when i call .Count(). What i don't get is how control is switched. I expected it to switch with await Task.Yield(). But it obviously didn't work like that i.e. lines:

    counter1: 6 is divisible by 2. Yielding
             counter2: 5
                         counter3: 3

Comment: If you are new to asynchronous programming then do not start with a console app. It's confusing because the synchronization context is not what you expect. Start with an app with a UI, like a winforms app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in a console application, so there's no synchronization context by default. After the first `await` runs, its continuation will be scheduled on another thread-pool thread. On the main thread, the second counter starts, and again when it reaches `await`, it will spawn another "branch". Those will then run in parallel, and you lose your expected order.

If you want to only have one task running at a time, you need to use a synchronization context or a task scheduler that schedules to only one thread.